# Compare columns of subset and superset CSVs and output intersecting column + another column of superset CSV in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Suppose that I have a CSV file called `super` that has columns-

`Num`, `Val`

1, 10

2, 25

3, 85

4, 87

And I have another CSV file `sub` that has a column-

`Num`

2

4

Now what I want is the output of the form-

`Num` ,`Val`

2, 25

4, 87

How can I achieve this in Pandas?

Comment: Why they are matched? What have you tried?

Comment: Right now I haven't tried anything. They aren't matched as such, it's just that I want to match them

Comment: Can you create a some dataset with code that people can use?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to guess what you are trying to achieve with this level of detail. But here is a first trial : is this what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
super = pd.read_csv("super.csv")
sub = pd.read_csv("sub.csv")
# Option 1 - using [merge][1]
result = pd.merge(super, sub, on="Num", how="inner")
# Option 2 - using the [isin][1] method
result = super.loc[super["Num"].isin(sub["Num"].unique())]
```